# Looping-Through-A-Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am preparing a Macro to loop through a number of cells in a column and check if their values are less than 200 if so, a message box appears in order to change such values. First, I select the active Cell (Starting Range is shown in image) to which all other cells are referenced to. However, this cell is a merged cell (2 merged cells). As shown in the given MWE. If I set the active cell to be in the form of 2 merged cells in the same column, then in the (For next loop), the first row (Yellow highlighted) is checked correctly if its value is less than 100, but it skips the second row and goes for the third row (Green highlighted). In the case of the active cell being a single cell rather than a merged one, then the process works correctly.

```
Sub ss()

    'Set active cell to which all offsets are related: On-screen selection
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Dim column_name As Range
    Set column_name = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the starting range(Column Name):", Title:="Starting range (Column Name)", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    column_name.Select

    `Check Minimum value for the known dimension
     Dim row_count As Single

     For row_count = 0 To 1
         If ActiveCell.Offset(row_count, 7).Value <= 200 Then
             If MsgBox(prompt:="Known dimension is less than or equal to minimum dimension", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Modify Known Dimension") = vbYes Then
                 ActiveCell.Offset(row_count, 7).Value = InputBox("Enter New value:", "Modifying known dimension", ActiveCell.Offset(row_count, 7).Value)
             End If
         End If
     Next row_count

End Sub
```

[Main Excel sheet setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E18DS.jpg)

Comment: The short answer is don't use merged cells.

Comment: Also avoid using `ActiveCell`, but instead use the direct reference `column_name`.